# $C_{k}$‐builder graphs introduced by Barefoot et al

Tags: graph-theory

I couldn't understand the construction of $C_{k}$-builder graphs. The definition says: A graph G is a $C_{k}$‐builder if G is $C_{k}$‐saturated, and there is a distinguished vertex v in G such that if v in one copy of G is identified with v in the other copy of G, then the resulting graph is $C_{k}$‐saturated.

What do they mean by the identification of v in the two copies of the graph?

What happens to the vertices and the edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $G_1=\langle V_1,E_1\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle V_2,E_2\rangle$ are graphs with disjoint vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$. Let $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$. The graph obtained by identifying $v_1$ and $v_2$ has vertex set $V=V_1\cup(V_2\setminus\{v_2\})$ and edge set

$$E=E_1\cup\big\{\{u,w\}\in E_2:u\ne v_2\ne w\big\}\cup\big\{\{v_1,u\}:\{v_2,u\}\in E_2\big\}\;.$$

In other words, you ‘glue’ the vertex $v_2$ of $G_2$ to the vertex $v_1$ of $G_1$ to make a single new vertex $v$; all of the edges in $G_1$ and $G_2$ that did not involve $v_1$ or $v_2$ remain unchanged, and $v$ is connected by an edge to every vertex in $G_1$ to which $v_1$ was connected and every vertex in $G_2$ to which $v_2$ was connected.

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both copies of a $C_k$-saturated graph $G$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ both correspond to the same vertex of $G$, and the graph obtained by identifying $v_1$ and $v_2$ is also $C_k$-saturated, then $G$ is a $C_k$-builder.